# Input in textarea does not display as typed in

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an inputarea for user to type some text. However, when the text gets updated it does not shows as the user has type in. For example, the new lines are not showing up.

Here is what the user typed in:

[image]

And here is how it shows up after update
(Everything goes into one line.):

[image]

Can someone please advise how to fix this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that "white-space:pre-line;" works as well. @splash58

Comment: It's not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to convert the new lines to br's or you can put the text in a `pre` element (or an element with `white-space: pre`* CSS).

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup',function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $('pre').html(text);
  $('article').html(text);
  $('div').html(text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />'))
})
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
pre {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
article {
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<pre></pre>

<div></div>

<article></article>
```